# Decreasing resolution when exporting PDF with plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pdf, resolution

I make a QGIS plugin to export PDF. However, the size of PDF is large and it takes a long time to open the file. Therefore, I want to export PDF with a small resolution.

How can I change the resolution?
Version of QGIS is "3.10.5-A Coruña".

Comment: Do you want to export to PDF of the layout in the print composer, or of the view of the main canvas?

Comment: I want to export to PDF of the layout in the print composer.